# How do I do webtesting in Perl for pages that require JavaScript?

Tags: linux, perl, automated-tests

I have found these two modules that purport to be able to puppet string browsers, but I have no experience with them, but my current test suite uses [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm).  Does anybody have any information about these modules, or other methods of testing pages from Perl that require JavaScript?

To clarify, I am running my tests under Linux (Ubuntu 7.10).

- [Mozilla::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mozilla-Mechanize/lib/Mozilla/Mechanize.pm)
- [GTK2::WebKit::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Gtk2-WebKit-Mechanize/lib/Gtk2/WebKit/Mechanize.pm)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try [WWW::Selenium](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/1.0-beta-2/doc/perl/), which uses your browser (through Perl) to handle JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, Selenium seems to be exactly the ticket.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to make use of [JavaScript::SpiderMonkey](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JavaScript::SpiderMonkey).